# New log and lock files created when redeploying app

Tags: java, jsf, logging

I'm logging in a JSF and ejb enviroment and every time I redeploy my app, the .lck files don't get deleted and a new log (and lock) file is created (logfilename.log.2, logfilename.log.3 ...)

This is how I get the log and add a filehandler in a JSF managed bean:

```
static {
  // (...)
  logger = Logger.getLogger("registrations");
  FileHandler fh;
  try {
    // (...)
    fh = new FileHandler(registerLogPath, true);
    fh.setFormatter(new Formatter() {

      @Override
      public String format(LogRecord record) {
        return ...
      }  
    });
    logger.addHandler(fh);
  } catch (IOException | SecurityException ex) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
}
```

I tried to remove the handlers in the `contextDestroyed` method of `ServletContextListener`, but it seems that it is too late since `Logger.getLogger("registrations").getHandlers()` returns an empty array, so nothing to remove.

Can you help me how to make the logger use the file it used before redeploying?

Comment: I'm still annoyed by this. Any ideas why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this. Removing a handler is not enough, you have to call `close()` on the handler itself. Also, `logger.getHandlers()` works in a `contextDestroyed` method:

```
for (Handler h : logger.getHandlers()) {
  h.close();
}
```